# How To Create Phone Number Format XXX-XXX-XXXX In Android

Tags: java, android

Can anybody help me to solve this problem ?

I want `"-"` between phone numbers. 
I tried . It shows `XXX-XXX-XXX-X` Formats only . But i want **`XXX-XXX-XXXX`** Format .

Here Below I have mentioned my code.

Declare This under Oncreate

```
TextView TxtDocPhone=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtDocPhone);

String numbersOnly = keepNumbersOnly(Phone);
String ProviderPhone = formatNumbersAsCode(numbersOnly);
```

Then call it

```
 private String keepNumbersOnly(CharSequence s) {
        return s.toString().replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""); 
    }

    private String formatNumbersAsCode(CharSequence s) {
        int groupDigits = 0;
        String tmp = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
            tmp += s.charAt(i);
            ++groupDigits;
            if (groupDigits == 3) {
                tmp += "-";
                // tmp += "";
                groupDigits = 0;
            }
        }
        return tmp;
    }
```

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i solve this issue . Just add below this in `formatNumbersAsCode` function .

```
 return  String.format("%s-%s-%s",s.subSequence(0,3),s.subSequence(3,6),s.subSequence(6,10));
```

Answer (score 3):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
String formattedNumber = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(unformattedNumber);
```

Take a look at [PhoneNumberUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html) for more options.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
private String formatNumbersAsCode(CharSequence s) {
    return String.format("%s-%s-%s",s.substring(0,3),s.substring(3,6),s.substring(6));
}
```

Comment: check my update. Just use small s. Made a mistake while typing.

Answer (score 1):

You best way to go is to use [Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

You know your phone number should have the format `XXX-XXX-XXXX`, so you just write an appropriate RegEx for this, and you are fine!

Answer (score 0):

Format with a `space (" ")` and then make a replaceall to the `"-"` character.